# Два и несколько

Tags: значение-слов

К какому количеству можно отнести слово "несколько"? Точнее, с какого по какое количество? И можно ли о двух предметах сказать, что их несколько?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Несколько - это столько, сколько человек не в состоянии сосчитать с первого взгляда, т.е. от трёх и более, правда тут важно и чего именно "несколько", у дробных показателей данное понятие может и раньше появится, но всё равно оно больше двух.

Знаете анекдот,- "Двое - это компания, а трое - уже толпа"? В языке так и есть (первый и второй к один и два этимологически не относятся, а третий уже явно от числа). Связано это скорей всего с тем, что нетренированный мозг без счёта воспринимает двоих, а на трёх ему уже нужен счёт. Самое интересное, что эту систему счёта (один, два, много) мы можем увидеть и в заимствованных словах. Латинские уно-, би-, ультра- и греческие моно-, ди-, поли- без труда вычленяются из состава заимствованных слов, а вот слова с тройкой найти уже намного сложнее.

В общем, несколько - это минимум трое, но понятие - это относительное и потому индивидуальное. Современный человек, как правило, на глаз 3-4 предмета или существа различает, поэтому *несколько* для него начинается с пяти, а то и выше.

Заканчивается же *несколько* там, где человек переходит на другой порядок счёта ( десяток, сотня, тысяча), что опять-таки очень индивидуально, но как правило "несколько" - это число чуть ниже числа следующего порядка (10, 100, 1000..).

Comment: >сколько человек не в состоянии сосчитать с первого взгляда, т.е. от трёх и более  
  
Это откуда же такие данные? Я "взглядом" считаю до семи-восьми предметов. 
Это совпадает с общими представлениями (искать сейчас не буду, позже, может; но читал неоднократно). Люди со специальной подготовкой - диспетчеры, скажем - могут и более: до двенадцати, кажется.

Comment: Вам повезло. Я вот сейчас посмотрел на одну из книжных полок, а там несколько книг. Пересчитал, книг ровно 8, а выведи меня в другую комнату и спроси, не ответил бы.

Естественно, при участии сознания, я способен удерживать и гораздо большие объёмы информации, но в непосредственной (бессознательной) памяти у меня "много" - это больше 5 предметов. Как показывает опыт задавания задачи про автобусные остановки (вышло столько-то, вошло столько, а сколько было остановок?), результат вполне приемлемый.  У диспетчеров уже другой тип памяти используется (диспетчерский).

Answer (score 4):

*С понятием **«несколько»** мы сталкиваемся ежедневно и повсеместно, но его метрические [количественные] свойства не определены. Для примера зададим вынесенный в заголовок вопрос самому себе, своим знакомым и получим очень интересные результаты.

- Так, например, на вопрос
     **««несколько»** - это сколько?», мы почти наверняка получим ответ, что
     **«несколько»** лежит в диапазоне [(**2 - 3**), (**10 - 15**)], **т.е.** нижняя граница интервала лежит на отметке 2 или 3, а
     верхняя на отметках от **10**.
- Если задать этот же вопрос в
     несколько другой форме: **««несколько
     сот»** - это сколько?», мы с удивлением
     обнаружим, что верхняя граница
     интервала значительно сместиться вниз
     и ответ будет: [**(2 - 3)**, **(6 - 7)**].
- Если ещё более усугубить вопрос и 
     задать его в следующей форме: 
  **««несколько тысяч»** - это сколько?»,
     то верхняя граница интервала 
     сместиться ещё больше и ответ будет
     выглядеть так: [(**2 - 3**), (**4 - 5)**].
- Пойдём дальше и зададим вопрос: 
  **««несколько миллионов»** - это 
     сколько?» и вопреки ожиданиям верхняя
     граница интервала в ответах 
     сместиться в большую сторону и ответ 
     будет примерно такой: [(**2 - 3**), (**5 - 
     6**)].
- Пока не будем останавливаться на 
     этом феномене в определении верхней
     границы интервала, а зададимся 
     вопросом: **Можно ли математически 

     точно определить интервал для понятия
     «несколько»?***

Comment: *Он повторил это несколько раз*. Ну максимум 4-5 раз, больше некуда! Пальцев одной руки должно хватить.

Answer (score 3):

Уже три ответа, и каждый написал по-разному. Полагаю, приведенные числовые диапазоны - это сугубо субъективные оценки самих написавших (или укажите, пожалуйста, что это за исследования).

Понимание слова "несколько" всегда зависит от контекста. Однозначно - более одного, точнее - как позволит фантазия. Слово "несколько" используют, когда точное количество не известно и/или не важно. Вот несколько примеров. Как вы поймете слово *несколько*?

"После урагана несколько населенных пунктов остались без электричества". Сколько населенных пунктов? Я по этой фразе понимаю, что известно по крайней мере о двух, и возникает предположение, что точное количество еще уточняется и на самом деле более двух.

"Машина пронеслась в нескольких метрах от меня". Тут уже вряд ли речь идёт о двух метрах. Без уточнения контекста, по этой фразе мне представляется как минимум метров 4-5.

"На птичьем дворе паслись куры, и нескольким из них удалось оказаться за забором". Сколько вам представилось кур, гуляющих за забором? Мне (опять же, без уточнения контекста) - от 3-4 до 15-20.

Comment: > (или укажите, пожалуйста, что это за исследования).  
  
Впервые - "НиЖ" в семидесятых годах. Подробности, естественно, в памяти стерлись.

а сейчас - вся сеть полна "исследованиями".
Ну вот хотя бы  
http://masterrussian.net/f15/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-13910/

>Тут уже вряд ли речь идёт о двух метрах.  

Скорее уж о полутора... Согласен, что когда "несколько" употребляется с измеряемыми, а не счетными объектами, значение ***несколько*** меняется.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, интересно. Получается, 4-6. Вот если бы исследования были помасштабнее... Всё-таки 17 респондентов - это не солидно.

Comment: Посмотрите в сети, там полно таких "исследований". Проблема только в том, что вопрос можно ставить по-разному. Лично я поставил бы его так:
Если проанализировать все случаи употребления слово "несколько", то в какой интервал они попадут с такой-то вероятностью. Про себя могу сказать, что на 99% процентов я скажу несколько в отношении 3-5 предметов, с абсолютной - про 2-7, ну, может 2-8 предметов. Никогда ни про 1, ни про 9 или более. И это всегда в отношении счетных предметов, независимо от их природы. Думаю, что большинство опрошенных ответят так же.

Answer (score 1):

"Юридически" - к любому, большему одного.
Более точно - в зависимости от контекста.

С минимальным значением как раз более или менее понятно:
"Я проверял [даже не один, а] несколько раз" - явно больше одного, т.е. два или более.
"Он переспросил [не два, а] несколько раз" - скорее всего больше двух.
Другие трактовки - уже вряд ли.

Тут дело в том, что у "несколько" де-факто может быть несколько значений:
а) все, что больше одного
б) все, что нельзя или не удалось точно посчитать, хотя это число небольшое.

Соответственно этому - и два приведенных значения.

А вот максимальное... тут контекст дает неограниченные возможности.
Но, исходя из разумного смысла и того факта, что на глаз (т.е. без пересчета каждого) человек способен оценить число до семи-восьми случайных или случайно расположенных предметов, полагаю, что в понимании говорящего обычно **"несколько" - это "от двух до семи" или "от двух до восьми"**.

Comment: Из указа Петра I :
> ... когда на большой Красной площади огненные потехи зажгут и стрельба будет, потом по знатным дворам боярам, и окольничим, и думным, и ближним, и знатным людям палатного, воинского и купецкого чина знаменитым людям каждому на своем дворе из небольших пушечек, буде у кого есть, и из нескольких мушкетов или иного мелкого ружья учинить трожды стрельбу и **выпустить несколько ракетов, сколько у кого случится,** и по улицам большим, где пространство есть, января с 1 по 7 число по ночам огни зажигать из дров, или хвороста...

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, в настоящее время:

1) слово "несколько" равнозначно словосочетанию "не очень много", а словосочетание "не очень много" равнозначно словосочетанию "обозримо много",

2) слово "несколько" неравнозначно словосочетанию "очень много".

Comment: Так есть, и так было в прошлом, но только вне точных величин (у Достоевского в Карамазовых: «потребуется несколько времени»). Сейчас Несколько стало Некоторым значением от и до.

Answer (score 0):

"Несколько" — это более двух, так как два — это "пара". "Пара случаев", "пара штук". Три уже "несколько штук". "Несколько" — это не более девяти, так как десять уже "десяток". То есть про 10 кур, ну и про 9, если торопиться и на глазок, скажешь: "с десяток кур оказалось за забором".

Comment: так как два — это "пара"? ========== Два не есть пара: например — несколько пар или две пары.

Comment: На чем основывается ваше убеждение? Почему "больше двух"? Вам оборот "один или несколько" знаком?